# Velocity framework resource not found exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to run velocity email sender program in Java 1.6 but its not finding recourse...

```
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("name", "mike");

    // Initialize the engine
    try {
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    templateName = "myfile_en.vm";

    // Load the template
    Template template = ve.getTemplate(templateName, "UTF-8");

    // Render the template into a writer
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    template.merge(context, writer);
```

Cam any one help me out why I'm not able to load myfile_en.vm??? I tried giving full absolute path as well but still same error: ResourceNotFound

I'm running it directly from eclipse. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the file located? What's the run configuration's starting directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on where your template file is. Velocity always has an issue with it. To get around it you need to ensure that the templates are locatable on your classpath. Either in a jar or on the filesystem directly. Once its on your classpath, init Velocity like this...

```
private static void initVelocity() throws Exception {
    java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties();
    p.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
    p.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    Velocity.init(p);
}
```

This tells Velocity to look for template files in the classpath.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add this initVelocity() method?? Do I need to add it in the same main program? How will it get invoked? Appreciate your help!

Comment: You need to invoke it from your main method before you work with velocity templates. In a servlet  container put this in the start up servlet - the one which is invoked by the servlet container when it starts up

Comment: I'm using a standalone java program....Can you please tell me where I should call this & how it'll get invoked?

Comment: Mike, first place your templates in a folder which in your classpath, then call the initVelocity() method before you work with your templates.. meaning...from your main method, first call initVelocity(), then go on to say VelocityContext ctx=new VelocityContext() and continue on.. initVelocity() needs to be called only once, before working with the Velocity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Only change the path into bean

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
      <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
          <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
          <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">
            org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
          </prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
```