# apache velocity resource not found exception even though template file is in the same directory

Tags: java, templates, velocity

i've learned of velocity as template engine and am trying it out in my code snippet.

```
package myproj.templating.velocity;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader;

public class velocityTest {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.init();

        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

        context.put( "name", new String("Velocity") );

        Template template = null;

        try
        {
           template = ve.getTemplate("mytemplate.vm");
        }
        catch (ResourceNotFoundException rne) {
            rne.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( ParseErrorException pee )

        {
          // syntax error: problem parsing the template
            pee.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch( MethodInvocationException mie )
        {
          // something invoked in the template
          // threw an exception
            mie.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        { e.printStackTrace();}

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        template.merge( context, sw );

        System.out.println("result= " + sw.toString());
    }
}
```

mytemplate.vm file is physically located in the same directory as this code and i've checked the spelling multiple times.  but i still get ResourceNotFound exception. what could be wrong? i've tried suggestions on stackflow to add filepath and what not but still gets the same exception.

Comment: tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737171/velocity-framework-resource-not-found-exception solution. didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

following set up did the trick.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
 p.setProperty("resource.loader","file");
 p.setProperty("file.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader");
 p.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path","/actual/full/path/here");           
 p.setProperty("file.resource.loader.cache", "false");
 p.setProperty("file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", "0");

ve.init(p);
```